# Compilation error on Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have MinGW installed on my computer (I just use the one shipped with Strawberry perl). I can compile things just fine from the command line. Using Eclipse CDT, however, results in weird errors. Using the c++ hello world default project which comes with Eclipse, compilation in CDT fails with these errors:

```
\**** Internal Builder is used for build               \****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\hw.o ..\src\hw.cpp
..\src\hw.cpp:9:20: error: iostream: No such file or directory
..\src\hw.cpp: In function 'int main()':
..\src\hw.cpp:13: error: 'cout' was not declared in this scope
..\src\hw.cpp:13: error: 'endl' was not declared in this scope
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 263  ms.
```

But when I run `g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\hw.o ..\src\hw.cpp` on my command line compilation goes just fine. All of the proper header files (like iostream) are in my path variable. What eclipse settings do I need to change to make this work?

Here's the file I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: Go to your project's properties, navigate to `C\C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes (tab)` and select the `GNU C++` language. Do you see a bunch of paths to your MinGW installation? Also, could you post the code you're trying to compiled (a simplified version). Finally do you have a MINGW_HOME environment variable set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced this only a few days ago, the problem turned out to be that I had both g++4.3 and g++4.4 installed and Eclipse was getting confused. I uninstalled 4.3 and the problem went away.